# Exp:resso registered members not mapped to Zoo Visitors

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor, 2.8

I know this is question has already been asked, but I just can't get it to work properly.

I have a member field called: member_billing_first_name

In my Exp:resso checkout form I have a field called billing_first_name 
which is mapped to member_billing_first_name in the backend

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    return="store_example/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'
    payment_method="PayPal_Express"
    register_member="yes"
}

<div>
    <label for="billing_first_name">Name</label>
    {field:billing_first_name}    
</div>
<div>
    <label for="order_email">Email Address</label>
    {field:order_email}{!-- this field is required --}
</div>
<div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    {field:password}{!-- this field is required --}
</div>

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

other html/links removed from example

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried this method, but no joy:
[Expresso Store 2: not mapping to Zoo Visitors fields on checkout](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/expresso-store-2-not-mapping-to-zoo-visitors-fields-on-checkout#answer-14774)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments in the question you linked to, Store doesn't support mapped member fields during registration with Zoo Visitor (due to ZV not correctly handling member registration hooks).

So your only option is to use the workaround in that thread, or craft your own workaround.

Alternatively, as I mentioned in your last question, you can simply create a login/registration page as step 2 of your checkout (it doesn't have to use the Store tags). That way your customers can create an account, then continue with the checkout. This is the way most websites work anyway.